# How to make select ui component as a required entry in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, ui-form

```
<form>
    ...
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <field name="select_example" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Select Example</label>
                <dataScope>select_example</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options>
                            <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #1</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #2</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="3" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #3</item>
                            </option>
                        </options>
                        <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        ...
    </fieldset>
    ...
</form>
```

i used this for to make dropdown in my form but how can i make this as required entry in my form
thanks

Comment: Where you created this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use this elements in your form

  Vendor_name/Module_name/view/adminhtml/ui_component

  ```
    <field name="select_example" sortOrder="50" formElement="select">
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Select Example</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor_name\Module_name\Model\Source\options"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
  ```
- Than create source file for options

namespace Vendor_name\Module_name\Model\Source;

```
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;


class options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
   
  public function toOptionArray(){
    
         return [
            ['label' => __('-- Please Select --'), 'value' => ''],
            ['label' => __('Option #1'), 'value' => '1'],
            ['label' => __('Option #2'), 'value' => '2'],
            ['label' => __('Option #3'), 'value' => '3'],
        ];
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: thanks @Abdullah it's working fine

Comment: Welcome @Mani please vote up

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your form elements:

```
<settings>
     <validation>
          <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
     </validation>
</settings>
```